# Не запускается графическая оболочка Arch Linux

Tags: linux, grub, archlinux

такая проблема. Собрал Arch Linux, поставил графическую оболочку Mate и LXDM. После того как я включил LXDM через команду systemctl enable lxdm.service и перезагрузил машину, у меня после загрузчика GRUB, когда должен прогрузиться LXDM, монитор выдает OUT OF RANGE 95.3kHz / 60Hz. Х-сервер поставил: pacman -S xorg xorg-server, Mate: pacman -S mate mate-extra, LXDM: pacman -S lxdm. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне это исправить. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Очевидно проблемы с настройками монитора, а точнее в частоте. Нужно поправить настройки xorg, о нём хорошо написано в арчвики. 
При запуске есть возможность переключиться в консоль по ctrl+alt+f(1-12)?